# apache2 .htaccess redirect subdirectory to domain without including path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am attempting to redirect a subfolder on an apache2 server to the root of an entirely different domain, without including the path of the folder in the new domain.

So, in mysite.com/folder-1/folder-2 I have a .htaccess file like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 / http://a-totally-different-site.com/
```

This sort of works, but includes the path in the redirect. So, when you visit mysite.com/folder-1/folder-2 it goes to a-totally-different-site.com/folder-1/folder-2

What I wish to happen, is for the subfolder to redirect to the root, so visiting mysite.com/folder-1/folder-2 will go to a-totally-different-site.com

Is this possible with .htaccess? I have tried a few different approaches I found, but none are working.

Comment: Do you want mysite.com/folder-1/folder-2/folder3 to go to a-totally-different-site.com or a-totally-different-site.com/folder3?

Comment: it should go to the root always. There isn't a folder-3 (it's just a one page super simple html site). Thanks!

Comment: _“but includes the path in the redirect”_ - works as designed, that is _exactly_ what the documentation for the Redirect directives says ...

Comment: @CBroe I know that that's exactly what it's meant to do... but I want to know if there's a way to not include the path

Comment: Not with a directive for which the manual explicitly states otherwise, no. You'll need a RewriteRule, as Dusan showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple rewrite rule should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://a-totally-different-site.com [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, got this working now. The redirect was being cached by my browser so when I tried this approach earlier it didn't work.